# preseed txt.cfg

Tags: system-installation, preseed, automatic

i'm gonna need your help :

I'm making an iso of ubuntu custom, everything works perfectly at one detail: I can't launch the installation without opening the menu at startup.

I modified the txt.cfg file by following tutorials on the internet, but nothing works, I find this menu.

Does anyone have a solution for me to bypass it completely?

My txt.cfg :

```
default live-install
label live-install
        menu label ^Install Ubuntu
        kernel /casper/vmlinuz
        append preseed/file=/cdrom/custom.preseed auto=true priority=critical debian-installer/locale=fr_FR keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=fr ubiquity/reboot=true languagechooser/language-name=French countrychooser/shortlist=FR localechooser/supported-locales=fr_FR.UTF-8 boot=casper automatic-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash noprompt noshell ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it !

I've just edit the isolinux.cfg to make it default ant it works :D